# Understanding DateTime.Now and ISO8601 'Z' designation

Tags: vb.net, iso8601

I am trying to get a handle on the interaction between DateTime.Now and ISO-8601 timezone designation for an API I am working on.  An endpoint incorporates a timestamp as criteria for the interrogation of our data historian.  The EndPoint returns the nearest previous 1/2 hour average for the datapoint requested and incorporates the following code:

```
If criteria.EndTime = "" Then
     timeStamp = DateTime.Now
Else
     timeStamp = CType(criteria.EndTime, DateTime)
End If
```

The body of the post accepts the following json:

```
 {
      "Interval": "30m",
      "StartTime": "",
      "EndTime": "2022-04-21T00:45:00Z",
      "TagList": "PointName",
      "Delim":",",
      "PointSource": "P",
      "ServerName": "PIServer"
 }
```

Where the EndTime is the parameter picked up by the endpoint.  We are currently in British Summer Time i.e. DST is UTC +01:00.  With the above criteria the data I get back is timestamped as follows:

```
[
  {
    "PointName": "PointName",
    "TimeStamp": "21/04/2022 01:30:00",
    "Value": "-2.3607"
  },
  {
    "PointName": "PointName",
    "TimeStamp": "21/04/2022 01:30:00",
    "Value": "-2.6333"
  }
]
```

As you can see the data returned is for 01:30 rather than the 00:30 that is expected.  If I leave the 'Z' designation out of the criteria then I get the correct content returned.  Can someone explain what is happening here please.

Comment: I would expect the 'Z' character to signify UTC.  Also see info on the "universal sortable" date/time format here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#UniversalSortable

Comment: Try running `Console.WriteLine(Date.Now.ToString("O"))` and `Console.WriteLine(Date.UtcNow.ToString("O"))` and you should see what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the client sent UTC based time (yours is) and the server responds in UTC time (it does **not**). As described, `...T00:30:00Z` (00:30:00 UTC) is the correct answer to your input of `...T00:45:00Z` based on what you said the endpoint does.

Now let's say the server responds in BST (which, it seems to) to the same UTC based client request. Then `...T01:30:00` (no time zone designation, assumed to be BST) is the correct answer for your input because 00:30:00 UTC is equivalent to 01:30:00 BST, which is the correct result given the server's rules.

I think you've missed the fact that the server appears to always be returning BST (perhaps that's local to the server) without a time zone designation (i.e. you could argue it should be returning `T01:30:00+1:00`)

It *appears* that if you send UTC (or any other time *with* time zone info), you get a BST response with no time zone designation, and if you send a time with no time zone info, the server assumes you're sending BST, and *still* returns BST.

So, when you remove the `Z` from your request, you get what you think is the wrong answer, but isn't because `T00:45:00` (aka 00:45:00 assumed BST) the server will respond with `T00:30:00` (aka 00:30:00 assumed BST).

I suspect if you sent `T00:45:00+1:00` you'd get back `T00:00:00+1:00`, but if you don't (i.e. no to zime zone info), then it might be a server bug. You could test this by sending `T00:45:00+2:00` and seeing if you get back `T00:00:00+2:00` or not.